# Android: Download thread stucks the app

Tags: android, download

My android application always gets stuck when downloading a file until the downloading is finished. However,the downloading thread is inherited from AyncTask and it is in background. Can anyone have a look and see what is wrong and how can i modify the code in order for it to work?

```
    private class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    File destFile;

    private boolean openAfterDownload;
    private Exception failure;

    public DownloadFileTask(boolean openAfterDownload) {
        this.openAfterDownload = openAfterDownload;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();           
        downloadDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.downloading));
        downloadDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            String url = params[0];
            LOG.debug("Downloading: " + url);

            String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(null, -1),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

                File destFolder = new File(config.getDownloadsFolder());
                if (!destFolder.exists()) {
                    destFolder.mkdirs();
                }

                /**
                 * Make sure we always store downloaded files as .epub, 
                 * so they show up in scans later on.
                 */
                if ( ! fileName.endsWith(".epub") ) {
                    fileName = fileName + ".epub";
                }

                destFile = new File(destFolder, URLDecoder.decode(fileName));

                if (destFile.exists()) {
                    destFile.delete();
                }

                // lenghtOfFile is used for calculating download progress
                long lenghtOfFile = response.getEntity().getContentLength();
                if(lenghtOfFile>=config.getAvailableSpace())
                {
                    this.failure = new Exception("not enough space");
                    return null;
                }
                // this is where the file will be seen after the download
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

                try {
                    // file input is from the url
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    // here's the download code
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len1 = 0;
                    long total = 0;

                    while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                        // Make sure the user can cancel the download.
                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        total += len1;
                        publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                        f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    }
                } finally {
                    f.close();
                }

            } else {
                this.failure = new RuntimeException(response
                        .getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
                LOG.error("Download failed: "
                        + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage() + "1",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            LOG.error("Download failed.", e);
            this.failure = e;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: how do you start the task? Do you by any chance create new DownloadFileTask and then call doInBackground()?

Comment: I start the DownloadFileTask in the main thread and after that the application can't run until the download finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are running your task in an `AsyncTask` but you have those lines of code:

```
    downloadDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.downloading));
    downloadDialog.show();
```

in your `onPreExecute()` method, which basically will start a DialogBox before the task it self starts.

What more I don't see the `onPostExecute()` method in your implementation. so you are never `.dismiss()` the dialog. But even if you did you are application still would be 'stack' (normal behavior) with this dialog until the download finishes.

Comment: Thanks Emil. So you mean that if i move the following lines of code, and dismiss the dialog in the onPostExecute method. My application will not get stuck any more?

    downloadDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.downloading));
    downloadDialog.show();

Comment: If you remove the following 2 lines of code, then there is no need to dismiss the dialog as you are never going to show it. this means that the AsyncTask is going to run in the background without the user even noticing it. the problem you might face this way is if you relay on the data  you are fetching using this AsyncTask then you need still need to wait until it finishes it's execution.